# Is it a bad practice to use setTimeout in a redux async action in order to mimic a slower response? React JS

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-redux, css-transitions, loading

I'm using Axios to fetch some data in a redux action and then display it with react. I'm keeping track of loading, error states of the request so I can display the appropriate components for better UX. Everything works fine but if you have a fast connection and my loading screen flashes in an instant. What would be the best was to address an issue like this? `setTimeout` works but feels kinda hacky to me.

Thanks in advance!
Kyle

Comment: Its actually good if the data loads quickly. However you can design your UI better so that the loading experience is better. For instance instead of showing a spinner, show the UI with transitions similar to what it will be with the data. https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcxl.com%2Fblog%2Fanimation-improve-user-experience%2F&psig=AOvVaw2GTD_vdPjjzed1BRlT9EWZ&ust=1588502349648000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCPD25cb-lOkCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAN

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it's a kind of "*fake async*" and it's also used for mocking purposes in testing;